# Skype webcam upside down but v4l1compat missing

Tags: linux-mint, camera, skype

I am running Linux Mint, but i think this issue will be mutual with Ubuntu. My webcam in Skype is upside down (in Cheese it's ok). There are a lot of topics dealing with this coming up with fix like this:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```

or similar modifications. Unfortunately, I don't have this file.

```
$ locate v4l1compat.so
```

outputs only:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
```

which doesn't work:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

Skype loads, but the webcam is still upside down.

I remember I've read somewhere that I should use 32bit libraries because of skype. But how can I get those? I tried simple copy from another Linux machine, but that unsurprisingly did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dependency search for `libv4l-0:i386`**

```
$ aptitude why libv4l-0:i386
i   ia32-libs                       Depends  ia32-libs-multiarch       
i A ia32-libs-multiarch:i386        Provides ia32-libs-multiarch
i A ia32-libs-multiarch:i386        Depends  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386
i A gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 Depends  libv4l-0:i386 (>= 0.5.0)
```

**To get `libv4l-0:i386`**

```
$sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

That will include `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so`

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: It did! I am sorry for a late answer. I did exactly what you wrote and the `*.so` files appeared in the folder. Using the `LD_PRELOAD` hint now works. Thx